# Softer jquery animation with floating elements

Tags: jquery, animation, web

First, have a look [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/evarildo/bQUw2/9/embedded/result/) and see how it works to understand my question better.

I'm making this Jquery animation to an institutional website and the idea is show the members faces. When you click, it expands a box on the middle of it with the member description.

The two animations are responsible for all the main changes.

```
$('.espaco').animate({width:"302px", height: "378px",margin: "1px", padding: "0px"},500);
$('.first').animate({width:"228px"},500);
```

The animation of the divs expanding and collapsing are lagging specially on the second occasion. All because of the floating elements changing position and it is making me crazy. Do you guys know any way to make it softer?

Comment: This is primarily a CSS question, a subject I am a bit weak in.  But, I don't see the need for two separate animations.  Since '.espaco' is always in the same position, regardless of which square is clicked, why not just place '.espaco' in the the middle where it is already rendering and:1.  Set '.espaco' width to 0.  On animate adjust width to the desired width.  The rest of the grid should take care of itself.

Comment: In other words, only animate '.espaco'

Comment: In this code, the animation in 'espaco' is one of the requirements of the project because it all have to be on the same space. While the div 'espaco' is hidden, the div 'banner' is shown, and vice versa. So the both divs 'first' have to adjust their sizes and is this process that isn't making the animation soft. Don't know if you saw the code, but here it is http://jsfiddle.net/evarildo/bQUw2/9/

Comment: I saw it, and then I realized how pointless my comment was.  Sorry

Comment: the squares are rearranging themselves, height and width.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution \o/. I have not changed a thing related to the class positioning, I just limited the size of their movements. First reduce the width a then the height. So it won't show the blank holes. It is knows as callback. It's essentially ordering the animation.

So this:

```
$('.espaco').animate({width:"0px",height:"228px",margin: "0px", padding: "0"},500);
```

Becomes this:

```
    $('.espaco').animate({height:"228px",margin: "0px", padding: "0px"},function (){
        $('.espaco').animate(
            {width:"0px"},
            {duration:500}
        );
    });
```

The final code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/evarildo/bQUw2/20/embedded/result/
Hope i could help someone!!